# How can I use a variable within an SVG path creation?

Tags: html, svg

I'm creating an SVG path using the Raphael library and the following code:

```
this.resultsBoxLine1 = paper.path("M42 10L42 36");
```

I would like to use variables to dictate the position of the path, however I cannot write like this:

```
this.resultsBoxLine1 = paper.path("MmyVar11 myVar2LmyVar3 myVar4");
```

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raphael path is just a string -- you can insert variables easily using `+` operator, e.g.:

```
this.resultsBoxLine1 = paper.path("M"+myVar11+" "+myVar2+"L"+myVar3+" "+myVar4);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this didn't cross my mind! You and SB both nailed it.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively

```
this.resultsBoxLine1 = paper.path("M{0} {1}L{2} {3}", myVar11, myVar2, myVar3, myVar4);
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I was unaware of this method.

Answer (score 1):

What about 
`paper.path("M" + myVar11 + " " + myVar2 + "L" + ...);`

Just use JavaScript string concats